# MySql Character to Date Format conversion returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have a char field which is having Date in it as **'26-Nov-2011'**
I want this date to be printed in **YYYY-MM-DD** format.

I used following date conversion which is not allowing me to do.

```
select date_format('26-Nov-2011','%d-%b-%y')
```

> returns Null.

I know date_format function can accept date in YYYY-DD-MM format but
Please let me know how to convert a Character to Required Date Format

Comment: It's not good to store dates in Char columns.

Comment: @ypercube : Yes ! I know but some time we need it for some scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26-Nov-2011', '%d-%b-%Y') dte;
```

Output:

```
2011-11-26
```

Comment: gave 3 hours for it. thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use STR_TO_DATE() to convert your strings to MySQL date values and ORDER BY the result

STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

[STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php) can be used with this format `'%d-%M-%Y'`, which will match the format of your current date string. Otherwise it will return `null`. Check on [date formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) as well.

```
select str_to_Date('26-Nov-2011','%d-%M-%Y')
from table1
;
```

Output:

```
| STR_TO_DATE('26-NOV-2011','%D-%M-%Y') |
-----------------------------------------
|       November, 26 2011 00:00:00+0000 |
```

- ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9403a/1)

Comment: @logan take a look at this please and comment :)

Comment: yes! You soln is working ... but it should be %b to get my required format. Thanks